# Cannot resolve symbol 'mapView' on android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-mapview

After tons of tries I couldn't found how to solve this.
Android won't resolve the symbol 'mapView' on:

```
  mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

What i'm trying to do is to get google maps to work on the emulator. 
I know this code is working on another PC, so my guess here that there's something else.. (a system issue or google maps api problem)

here's the code.
Can anyone help? Thank you..

```
    package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.AsyncResponse;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

/**
 * Created by matant on 8/24/2015.
 */
public class GoogleMapFragmentController extends Fragment implements AsyncResponse {
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_map_fragment_controller, container,
                false);
        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume();//    display map immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

        // Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        // Perform any camera updates here
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResponse(String resStr) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataToDBController() {

    }

    @Override
    public void preProcess() {

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.matant.gpsportclient"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.matant.gpsportclient.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.matant.gpsportclient.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.ForgotPassword"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.SignUp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 "
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.matant.gpsportclient"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('C:/Users/Adi/AndroidStudioProjects/GPSportClient/libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/Adi/AndroidStudioProjects/GPSportClient/libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/Adi/AndroidStudioProjects/GPSportClient/libs/activation.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First of all, you put wrong findviewbyId.set R.id.map instead mapview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

with

```
 mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
```

as the id of your fragment is `map`. See the xml

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: Ok, Done.. now when the app is running it crashes... 
... got the "unfortunately... has stopped".

     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

Comment: Too much explanation needed for that error..could you please ask that as a new question..